# Get CPU usage (in %)

Tags: windows, cpu-usage, autoit

I'd like to get CPU usage (in %) to a variable with AutoIt. Is there a function like [`MemGetStats()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MemGetStats.htm) for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found the solution:

```cpp
Func _Processor_Usage()
    Local $s_Text       = ''
    Dim $Obj_WMIService = ObjGet('winmgmts:\\' & @ComputerName & '\root\cimv2')

    If IsObj($Obj_WMIService) And Not @error Then
        Dim $Col_Items = $Obj_WMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor')

        Local $Obj_Item
        For $Obj_Item In $Col_Items
            Local $s_Text = $Obj_Item.PercentProcessorTime & '%'
        Next

        Return String($s_Text)
    EndIf

    Return 0
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 2):

WMI is slow. [The following solution](https://autoit.de/index.php?thread/11082-hardware-auslastung-ermitteln/) returns faster and includes information per processor core:

```
$aUsage = _GetCPUUsage()
For $i = 1 To $aUsage[0]
    ConsoleWrite('CPU #' & $i & ' - ' & $aUsage[$i] & '%' & @CRLF)
Next

;#####################################################################
;# Function: _GetCPUUsage()
;# Gets the utilization of the CPU, compatible with multicore
;# Return:   Array
;#           Array[0] Count of CPU, error if negative
;#           Array[n] Utilization of CPU #n in percent
;# Error:    -1 Error at 1st Dll-Call
;#           -2 Error at 2nd Dll-Call
;#           -3 Error at 3rd Dll-Call
;# Author:   Bitboy  (AutoIt.de)
;#####################################################################
Func _GetCPUUsage()
    Local Const $SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION = 8
    Local Const $SYSTEM_TIME_INFO = 3
    Local Const $tagS_SPPI = "int64 IdleTime;int64 KernelTime;int64 UserTime;int64 DpcTime;int64 InterruptTime;long InterruptCount"

    Local $CpuNum, $IdleOldArr[1],$IdleNewArr[1], $tmpStruct
    Local $timediff = 0, $starttime = 0
    Local $S_SYSTEM_TIME_INFORMATION, $S_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
    Local $RetArr[1]

    Local $S_SYSTEM_INFO = DllStructCreate("ushort dwOemId;short wProcessorArchitecture;dword dwPageSize;ptr lpMinimumApplicationAddress;" & _
    "ptr lpMaximumApplicationAddress;long_ptr dwActiveProcessorMask;dword dwNumberOfProcessors;dword dwProcessorType;dword dwAllocationGranularity;" & _
    "short wProcessorLevel;short wProcessorRevision")

    $err = DllCall("Kernel32.dll", "none", "GetSystemInfo", "ptr",DllStructGetPtr($S_SYSTEM_INFO))

    If @error Or Not IsArray($err) Then
        Return $RetArr[0] = -1
    Else
        $CpuNum = DllStructGetData($S_SYSTEM_INFO, "dwNumberOfProcessors")
        ReDim $RetArr[$CpuNum+1]
        $RetArr[0] = $CpuNum
    EndIf
    $S_SYSTEM_INFO = 0

    While 1
        $S_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION = DllStructCreate($tagS_SPPI)
        $StructSize = DllStructGetSize($S_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION)
        $S_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION = DllStructCreate("byte puffer[" & $StructSize * $CpuNum & "]")
        $pointer = DllStructGetPtr($S_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION)

        $err = DllCall("ntdll.dll", "int", "NtQuerySystemInformation", _
            "int", $SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION, _
            "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($S_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION), _
            "int", DllStructGetSize($S_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION), _
            "int", 0)

        If $err[0] Then
            Return $RetArr[0] = -2
        EndIf

        Local $S_SYSTEM_TIME_INFORMATION = DllStructCreate("int64;int64;int64;uint;int")
        $err = DllCall("ntdll.dll", "int", "NtQuerySystemInformation", _
            "int", $SYSTEM_TIME_INFO, _
            "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($S_SYSTEM_TIME_INFORMATION), _
            "int", DllStructGetSize($S_SYSTEM_TIME_INFORMATION), _
            "int", 0)

        If $err[0] Then
            Return $RetArr[0] = -3
        EndIf

        If $starttime = 0 Then
            ReDim $IdleOldArr[$CpuNum]
            For $i = 0 to $CpuNum -1
                $tmpStruct = DllStructCreate($tagS_SPPI, $Pointer + $i*$StructSize)
                $IdleOldArr[$i] = DllStructGetData($tmpStruct,"IdleTime")
            Next
            $starttime = DllStructGetData($S_SYSTEM_TIME_INFORMATION, 2)
            Sleep(100)
        Else
            ReDim $IdleNewArr[$CpuNum]
            For $i = 0 to $CpuNum -1
                $tmpStruct = DllStructCreate($tagS_SPPI, $Pointer + $i*$StructSize)
                $IdleNewArr[$i] = DllStructGetData($tmpStruct,"IdleTime")
            Next

            $timediff = DllStructGetData($S_SYSTEM_TIME_INFORMATION, 2) - $starttime

            For $i=0 to $CpuNum -1
                $RetArr[$i+1] = Round(100-(($IdleNewArr[$i] - $IdleOldArr[$i]) * 100 / $timediff))
            Next

            Return $RetArr
        EndIf

        $S_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION = 0
        $S_SYSTEM_TIME_INFORMATION = 0
        $tmpStruct = 0
    WEnd
EndFunc
```

Comment: Thank you for the precision. I'll try it as soon as possible.